# Docker image missing after reboot PC

Tags: docker

I am working with this docker file; 
https://github.com/gioargyr/docker-kr-suite
After I connected docker repository one time i rebooted PC and it has gone. How I can make it permanent.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

That docker image is not gone you might need to start it again.
First you need to check available docker list using following command

```
docker ps -a
```

This will list all the containers available

```
docker ps
```

Only shows currently running images. Once you find your image you can run it using command

```
docker start <container name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and restarting docker with the command below solved it for me.

**sudo systemctl restart docker.service**

Note: You can consider making docker start at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `docker` service to run at startup:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

And then you'll have to run the `docker` service (only this time, it will run automatically at the next restart):

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Or even:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

The answer with the `restart` command will work but won't survive a startup.